# How to write a unit test to check if modal shows up after clicking some link

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

I am just learning unit testing with Jest/Enzyme - specifically for React/Redux.
I am trying to write a test to check from user perspective (is this correct approach?...) if modal shows up after clicking some link.
Next I want to test if clicking on `shade` wrapper over `modal` closes `modal`.

Modal state (open/closed) is controlled by Redux.

Based on current state from Redux - modal gets appropriate style: `modal` or `invisibleModal`.

I have tried to do it by mocking Redux store but I feel it should be done without it - I suppose it would be better to test unconnected component, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Test so far:

```
const mockFn = jest.fn();

describe('Contact components', ()=>{
    it('<ContactModal /> renders correctly', ()=>{
        shallow(<ContactModal />)
    })

    it('<ContactForm /> renders correctly', ()=>{
        shallow(<ContactForm toggleContactModal={mockFn} />)
    })

});

describe('In contact form link',()=>{
    const link = shallow(<ContactForm toggleContactModal={mockFn}/>)
    const modalWrapper = shallow(<ContactModal />);

    it('toggleContactModal function is called upon clicking ContactForm',()=>{
        expect(modalWrapper.find('#modal').hasClass('modal')).toBe(false);
        link.simulate('click');

        expect(mockFn.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
    })
})
```

Modal component:

```
export const ContactModal = props => {
    return (
        <>
            <div 
                id='modal' 
                className={props.contactModal ? styles.modal : styles.invisibleModal}
            >
                hello from modal
            </div>
            <div 
                id='shade' 
                className={props.contactModal ? styles.shade : styles.invisibleShade} 
                onClick={props.toggleContactModal}
                onKeyDown={props.toggleContactModal}
            />
        </>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps =state=> {
    return {
        contactModal: state.contactModal
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    toggleContactModal
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ContactModal);
```

Reducer:

```
export const contactModal = (state=false, action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case TOGGLE_CONTACT_MODAL:
            return !state;
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Writing Tests](https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests#connected-components) Redux doc:

> ...sometimes you want to test just the rendering of the component, without a Redux store.
>
> In order to be able to test the App component itself without having to deal with the decorator, we recommend you to also export the undecorated component

So yes, exporting the unconnected component and testing it directly is a recommended approach.

---

For your component you just need to test the UI changes based on the `contactModal` prop, and the click and keydown handlers.

Here is a slightly simplified working example to get you started:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

const ContactModal = props => {
  return (
    <>
      <div
        id='modal'
        className={props.contactModal ? 'modal': 'invisibleModal'}
      >
        hello from modal
          </div>
      <div
        id='shade'
        className={props.contactModal ? 'shade' : 'invisibleShade'}
        onClick={props.toggleContactModal}
        onKeyDown={props.toggleContactModal}
      />
    </>
  );
};

describe('ContactModal', () => {
  it('should render as expected when contactModal is true', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<ContactModal contactModal={true} />);
    expect(wrapper.find('#modal').prop('className')).toBe('modal');  // Success!
    expect(wrapper.find('#shade').prop('className')).toBe('shade');  // Success!
  });
  it('should render as expected when contactModal is false', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<ContactModal contactModal={false} />);
    expect(wrapper.find('#modal').prop('className')).toBe('invisibleModal');  // Success!
    expect(wrapper.find('#shade').prop('className')).toBe('invisibleShade');  // Success!
  });
  it('should call props.toggleContactModal on click', () => {
    const spy = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = shallow(<ContactModal contactModal={true} toggleContactModal={spy} />);
    wrapper.find('#shade').prop('onClick')();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();  // Success!
  });
  it('should call props.toggleContactModal on keydown', () => {
    const spy = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = shallow(<ContactModal contactModal={true} toggleContactModal={spy} />);
    wrapper.find('#shade').prop('onKeyDown')();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();  // Success!
  });
});
```

Comment: I also recommend looking at [`enzyme-to-json`](https://github.com/adriantoine/enzyme-to-json#readme) which lets you verify your UI easily and intuitively using [snapshot testing](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/snapshot-testing).

Comment: Awsome! It really helped me. I tried some aproaches, but still testing doesn't feel completly intuitive for me. I am still getting into it. I will look into snapshots, but just thought that in this case it wouldn't work, becasue UI pretty much changes by modal being visible or not. Am I not correct? I feel like I am missing something concerning when to decide on snapshots or not.

Comment: If the visibility is controlled with css styling (like `display: none`) it will still exist in the rendered output (even though it won't be visible in the browser), so it will also show up in snapshots serialized with `enzyme-to-json` @ErykLudwin